# Scala implicit ClassManifest[T] is null in Array.fill(..)

Tags: generics, scala, null, matrix, scala-2.8

I started messing around with generics in Scala, and it is a tough cookie to break. My idea is to learn it by writing a generic matrix class for use in my parallel computing project.

However, I have trouble using Array.fill() when instantiating a new matrix. Here is my code for the Matrix:

(beware of brickwall)

---

```
package dm8xx.matrix.immutable
import scala.util.Random

/*
 * Bring your sunglasses...
 */

object Matrix {
  def apply[T](m: Int, n: Int, v: T )(implicit nn:Numeric[T],mm:ClassManifest[T]): Matrix[T] = {
    println("making new mat")
    println(mm)
      new Matrix[T](Array.fill(m,n)(v))
  }
  def apply[T: Numeric](m: Int, n: Int): Matrix[T] = Matrix(m, n)
  def apply(m: Int, n: Int, r: Random): Matrix[Double] =
    new Matrix(Array.fill[Double](m, n) { Math.floor(r.nextDouble() * 100) })

}

class Matrix[T: Numeric](val data: Array[Array[T]]) {
  val num = implicitly[Numeric[T]]
  implicit val cm: ClassManifest[T] = implicitly
  val m = data.size
  val n = data(0).size
  def apply(i: Int, j: Int) = data(i)(j)

  def map(f:T=>T)= new Matrix(data.map(_.map(f)))

  def pieceWise(f: (T, T) => T, that: Matrix[T]): Matrix[T] = {
    val temp: Array[Array[T]] = Array.ofDim[T](m, n)
    for (i <- 0 until m; j <- 0 until n) temp(i)(j) = f(data(i)(j), that.data(i)(j))
    return new Matrix(temp)
  }
  def +(that: Matrix[T]) = pieceWise(num.plus(_, _), that)
  def -(that: Matrix[T]) = pieceWise(num.minus(_, _), that)
  def *(that: Matrix[T]) = {
    val temp = Matrix[T](m,that.n,num.one)
    for (i <- 0 until m; j <- 0 until n; k <- 0 until that.n)
      temp.data(i)(k) = num.plus(temp.data(i)(k) , num.times( data(i)(j) , that.data(j)(k)))
    temp
  }

  override def toString() = (for (i <- 0 until m) yield "\n" + (for (j <- 0 until n) yield data(i)(j))).toString

}
```

---

Everything compiles and I can even run my test but it fails at a certain point. The test I am running looks as follows:

```
  val M = 100
  val N = 100
  val threads = false
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val r = new Random(2)
    val a: Matrix[Double] = Matrix(M, N, r)
    val b: Matrix[Double] = Matrix(N, M, r)
    println(a)
    println(b)
    var m12 = a * b
  }
```

This fails with the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" scala.MatchError: null
    at scala.reflect.ClassManifest$.arrayType(ClassManifest.scala:206)
    at scala.Array$.fill(Array.scala:254)
    at dm8xx.matrix.immutable.Matrix$.apply(Matrix.scala:12)
    at dm8xx.matrix.immutable.Matrix.$times(Matrix.scala:37)
    at dm8xx.matrix.MatrixTest$.main(MatrixTest.scala:19)
    at dm8xx.matrix.MatrixTest.main(MatrixTest.scala)
```

Can someone tell me why the class manifest is null at this point? Sorry about putting so much code, but I cannot tell at which point my error lies, so I must report everything. (Maybe I can delete irrelevent parts when I get a good answer).

---

---

Okay, now the code works, but of course its at least 10 times slower than a direct implementation with Double for example...this is what the final matrix looks like (if anyone is interested):

```
package dm8xx.matrix.immutable
import scala.util.Random

/*
 * Bring your sunglasses...
 */

object Matrix {
  def apply[T](m: Int, n: Int, v: T)(implicit nn: Numeric[T], mm: ClassManifest[T]): Matrix[T] = {
    new Matrix[T](Array.fill(m, n)(v))
  }
  def apply[T](m: Int, n: Int)(implicit num: Numeric[T], cm: ClassManifest[T]): Matrix[T] = Matrix[T](m, n, num.zero)
  def apply(m: Int, n: Int, r: Random): Matrix[Double] =
    new Matrix(Array.fill[Double](m, n) { Math.floor(r.nextDouble() * 100) })
}

class Matrix[T: Numeric: ClassManifest](val data: Array[Array[T]]) {
  val num = implicitly[Numeric[T]]
  val cm: ClassManifest[T] = implicitly
  val m = data.size
  val n = data(0).size
  def apply(i: Int, j: Int) = data(i)(j)

  def map(f: T => T) = new Matrix(data.map(_.map(f)))

  def pieceWise(f: (T, T) => T, that: Matrix[T]): Matrix[T] = {
    val temp: Array[Array[T]] = Array.ofDim[T](m, n)
    for (i <- 0 until m; j <- 0 until n) temp(i)(j) = f(data(i)(j), that.data(i)(j))
    return new Matrix(temp)
  }
  def +(that: Matrix[T]) = pieceWise(num.plus(_, _), that)
  def -(that: Matrix[T]) = pieceWise(num.minus(_, _), that)
  def *(that: Matrix[T]) = {
    val temp = Matrix[T](m, that.n, num.zero)
    for (i <- 0 until m; j <- 0 until n; k <- 0 until that.n)
      temp.data(i)(k) = num.plus(temp.data(i)(k), num.times(data(i)(j), that.data(j)(k)))
    temp
  }

  override def toString() = (for (i <- 0 until m) yield "\n" + (for (j <- 0 until n) yield data(i)(j))).toString

}
```

Comment: Can someone recommend a good explanation of using implicit values for type inference, or maybe give a good short explanation with examples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
class Matrix[T: Numeric: ClassManifest](val data: Array[Array[T]]) {
  val num = implicitly[Numeric[T]]
  val cm: ClassManifest[T] = implicitly
...
```

Comment: Yes it does. Why is that? Also, in the * function it should be num.zero instead of num.one, if anyone is interested.

Comment: @Felix Because, otherwise, methods over `data` which create new arrays would not have a `ClassManifest` available.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Manifest` instead of `ClassManifest`

Arrays need extra handling when containing primitives because they're reified, but `ClassManifest`is intended to work with classes (the name is a give away)